# Wrong coordinate

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, references

I'm working on Sudan
I opened a Google map layer from the quick map services
I don't know how to set the project coordinate system to get to correct longitude and latitude 
Should the project have a different CRS than the map layer? 
What coordinate system system should I use for the project and the map layer

Comment: QGIS is capable of `on-the-fly` reprojection, thus being able to display layers of different CRS simultaneously. As to which CRS you should use, the answer is: One that fits your area of interest.

Comment: If you are using quick map services as your basemap then many of them will automatically change your project projection to epsg:3857 (web mercator) as they are xyz tiles and are incapable of using a different projection.

Comment: @Erik should the main CRS and the map layer CRS be different?

Comment: There is no should or shouldn't, rather use a sensible CRS for the data you're really working with, don't care about fitting the rest, since QGIS does it automatically.

Comment: @IanTurton what you said is true 
but when I use the zoom to coordinate plugin it displays a wrong location
should I change the map layer's CRS?

Comment: @Erik there are two types of CRS :
geographic coordinate systems and projected coordinate systems
I used the 1st as a main CRS and the 2nd for the map layer

Comment: Just make sure you understand things right: there is a CRS for your project, bottom right of your QGIS-window (or in project-settings). You can chosse this CRS freely (as long as it fits your region of interest). Use e.g. EPSG 3857 for WebMaps. The other CRS are layer-CRS (in layer properties): they can't be chosen, they MUST be set to the CRS the layer was created in. So find out what kind of layer you load and in what CRS it was designed - check if it's CRS in QGIS is set correctly (layer-context-menu: set CRS). If you have PROJECT CRS 3857 and every LAYER in its own CRS, it should work.